# Is there any good tool to view and browse ant build file?

Tags: java, ant, build

I found it is hard to read an ant build file. Especially if the build file has lots of imported files, like property file and other xml build file.

Therefore, I am wondering if there are some good tools that can help, like viewing and browsing source code in IDE.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Eclipse has provided Ant build plugin where it can outline each XML element of Ant build file into a tree of elements for easy view. However, the edits will be done in text.

Comment: @Smartmarkey IntelliJIDEA will be a good choice if you are also using Java. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/ant_maven.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [GRAND, here](http://www.ggtools.net/grand/)

Super easy to use and setup.

Answer (score 4):

ant2dot (https://github.com/pvdb/ant2dot) will transform your ant build file into a dot file, which you can then use graphviz to turn into an image of the task dependencies in your build script. You can even automate that process with an ant task in the build file.

Its great if that's the level of detail you're looking fore. Otherwise the best I've seen is just your basic XML structure inside a tree control. IIRC Netbeans does this.

Answer (score 0):

I think Eclipse does a good job.  It will even do basic error checking for you --like the opening and closing of tags and validation of path vars.